# Pop-up calendar on click of certain cells

Tags: excel, vba

If cells G8 or A11:A29 are clicked, I want a pop up calendar to pop up and place the date within that/those selected cell(s). We will want to use the pop up calendar on other files and other users' PCs, though the files will vary in where we want the cells to display the pop up calendar. Would an add in be used for this or can I simply figure out the code and include it in other workbooks? I had five users counting myself that could run my new file without issue but there are at least three users who get a "Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine" error message when clicking within the specified cells. Some of the links I used: [Extend Office](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4346-excel-click-cell-popup-calendar.html) [VBA Express](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-10914.html) [Font Stuff](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut07.htm)

Code In sheet 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A11:A29")) Is Nothing Then frmCalendar.Show
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G8")) Is Nothing Then frmCalendar.Show
End Sub
```

Code in Module 1: (Not even sure I need this. I think this was originally because I had buttons)

```
Sub OpenCalendar()
frmCalendar.Show
End Sub
```

Code in frmCalendar:

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
On Error Resume Next
Dim xRg As Object
For Each xRg In Selection.Cells
xRg.Value = DateClicked
Next xRg
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
If IsDate(ActiveCell.Value) Then
Me.MonthView1.Value = ActiveCell.Value
End If
End Sub
```

I truly appreciate any and all help or point in the right direction! Cheers!

Comment: `At the start of ` .... reading your post, I saw a massively long text block and it turned me off from reading anymore of your question. Please edit your question for brevity, clarity and readability. Create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and tell us only what we need to know to help.

Comment: This will require you to create a userform. On the userform toolbox, right click and add the control: [`Microsoft MonthView Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276348(v=vs.60).aspx). You can then open up this form when you make your selection on the sheet.

Comment: I already created the close button and calendar on the userform. It works on most PCs but not every ones.